# How to put a correct ahref

Tags: html, css

I need some help. I have a grid with some images. I want them to be clickable, so I added a  tag, but when I'm doing this my whole images disappears almost. I think there is something wrong because it is in the container div (see code below). but I can't figure out what is wrong. The text under the image must be clickable too, so that's why I put it in the a href also. The problem with the text is that the underline isn't going away when I do: text-decoration: none;. I don't know how I can fix this all. Anyone have an idea? See screenshot below how it looks like now.

HTML Code:

```
<section class="country">
        <h1>Our country</h1>
        <div class="container2">
            <a href="sub_history.html">
                <div class="history">
                    <p>History</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="culture">
                <p>Culture</p>
            </div>
            <div class="demo">
                <p>Demographics</p>
            </div>
            <div class="geo">
                <p>Geographics</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And CSS:

```
.country {
    height: 85vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.country h1 {
    padding-top: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25%, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 450px);
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.container2>div>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.history {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%), url("images/4ond/hist.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.culture {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%), url("images/4ond/culture.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.demo {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%), url("images/4ond/demo.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.geo {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%), url("images/4ond/geo.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.history p,
.culture p,
.demo p,
.geo p {
    margin-top: 95%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

[image]

Hope somebody could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor tags are by default meant as inline elements. So instead of being the container, it's supposed to be the anchor inside the container. (Although that's mostly history now a days and your approach is fine, but still let me show you how you could structure your code that way and solve your problem )

```css
.country {
    height: 85vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif; /* remove for own style */
}

h1 {
    padding-top: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25%, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 450px);
    margin-top: 5%;
}

h2 a{
    display: block;
    padding-top: 95%;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: lightgrey; /* Remove this, only used to show the elements */
    border: solid 1px black; /* Remove this, only used to show the elements */
}

.history h2 a{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%), url("images/4ond/hist.jpg");
}

.culture h2 a {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%), url("images/4ond/culture.jpg");
}

.demo h2 a {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%), url("images/4ond/demo.jpg");
}

.geo h2 a {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%), url("images/4ond/geo.jpg");
}
```

```html
<section class="country">
  <h1>Our country</h1>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="history">
      <h2><a href="#">History</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="culture">
      <h2><a href="#">Culture</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="demo">
      <h2><a href="#">Demographics</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="geo">
      <h2><a href="#">Geographics</a></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! I understand it now and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the background of the "a" tag not the div

```
<a class="history" href="sub_history.html">
<div>
<p>History</p>
</div>
</a>
```

and for the "p" tag put the margin 90% (it's better)

Comment: Okay, I will try. Thank you!

Comment: It worked, thank you, but the underline under the <p> is stillt here. Even when I do text-decoration none

Comment: you did a{text-decoration: none;} or p{text-decoration: none;} ?

Comment: Yeah I did, but TS helped me out. But thank you for you help though!